# System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method on batch within batch

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

I am attempting to call a batch within a batch. The reason why I am attempting this is because the values returned in the main batch is used in a query to grab other records to be updated from a different object. The sample code below might do a better job of explaining this :

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

    System.Debug('====> In AccountAssignmentBatch2');
    List<Zip_Code__c> zipList = new List<Zip_Code__c>();
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    Set<String> zipSet = new Set<String>();
    // loop through the zipcode records
    for (sObject s : scope) {
        // cast the sObject to zip code
        Zip_Code__c zip = (Zip_Code__c)s;
        zipSet.add(zip.zip_code__c);
        // update the zip code record to show it was processed
        zip.update_required__c = false;
        zipList.add(zip);
        System.debug('====> In AccountAssignmentBatch2: Processing Zip ' + zip.Zip_Code__c);
    }

    database.executeBatch(new AccountAssignmentBatchHelper('select id, Assignment_Error__c from account where zip5__c in :zipSet'));
    /*List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>([select id, Assignment_Error__c from account where zip5__c in :zipSet]);
    for (Account a : accountsList) {
        a.Assignment_Error__c = null;
        accountsToUpdate.add(a);
    }

    // trigger an update on the accounts.
    System.Debug('====> Size of accounts to update is : ' +accountsToUpdate.size() );
    if (accountsToUpdate.size() > 0) update accountsToUpdate;*/

    System.Debug('====> Size of zips to update is : '+zipList.size());        
    // update zip code records 
    if (zipList.size() > 0) update zipList;

}
```

The lines of code commented out were originally part of this main code but I moved them into the new batch class which I call the AccountAssignmentBatchHelper because I was encountering governor limits issue with the number of soql calls being made. This saves without issues but when I run my test class I encounter the error :  **System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.** 
Can someone explain why this is happening and how I may be able to resolve this? Thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can chain batches only through the finish() method.  The reason for this is that the execute() method will be called many times for a given batch start() and this can get out of hand with too many batches scheduled.

Have your batchable class implement `Database.stateful` and save any information you need as class member variables, available to the finish() method for starting the next batch

From the Apex doc:

> Starting with Apex saved using Salesforce.com API version 26.0, you
>   can call Database.executeBatch or System.scheduleBatch from the finish
>   method. This enables you to start or schedule a new batch job when the
>   current batch job finishes. For previous versions, you can’t call
>   Database.executeBatch or System.scheduleBatch from any batch Apex
>   method. Note that the version used is the version of the running batch
>   class that starts or schedules another batch job. If the finish method
>   in the running batch class calls a method in a helper class to start
>   the batch job, the Salesforce.com API version of the helper class
>   doesn’t matter.

Comment: crop1645 - thanks for that. Changing my code and testing out your suggestion in my org. Will update.